# Regex to separate words numbers and symbols in php

Tags: php, regex

I have the following sample string

> Lot99. Is it 1+3 or 5 or 6.53

I would like the following result

```
["Lot99",".","Is","it","1","+","3","or","5","or","6.53"]
```

So results eliminate spaces, separates words but keep together words and numbers if there is no space between them, separates numbers if not at start or end of word. Separates symbols like `+-.,!@#$%^&*();\/|<>` but not if a decimal point between 2 numbers, eg 2.2 should be kept as 2.2

So far I have this regex `/s+[a-zA-Z]+|\b(?=\W)/`

I know its not much but I have been visiting a number of websites to learn RegEx but I am still trying to get my head around this language. If your answer could please include comments so I can break it down and learn from it so I can then eventually start to modify it further.

Comment: Should consecutive special symbols be counted as one or different ? For example should `.>$` be counted as 1 or 3 different results ?

Comment: @noob 3 different results unless . is a decimal in a number as described above.

Comment: You should mention that in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `preg_match_all`

```
preg_match_all('~(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\w)+|[^\s\w]~', $str, $matches);
```

<kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eX0kY5/2)**</kbd>

Explanation:

- `(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\w)+` would match numbers (float or int) or word characters one or more times which matches strings like `foo99.9` , `88gg` etc
- `|` OR
- `[^\s\w]` matches a non-word , non-space character.

Answer (score 1):

To provide yet another alternative, `PHP` offers the wonderful `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` construct. What it says, is the following:

```
dont_match_this|forget_about_this|(but_keep_this)
```

Breaking it down to your actual problem, this would be:

```
        (?:\d+\.\d+)    # looks for digits with a point (float)
        (*SKIP)(*FAIL)  # all of the left alternatives should fail
        |               # OR
        ([.\s+]+)       # a point, whitespace or plus sign 
                        # this should match and be captured
                        # for PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE
```

In `PHP` this would be:

```
<?php

$string = "Lot99. Is it 1+3 or 5 or 6.53";
$regex = '~
            (?:\d+\.\d+)    # looks for digits with a point (float)
            (*SKIP)(*FAIL)  # all of the left alternatives should fail
            |               # OR
            ([.\s+]+)       # a point, whitespace or plus sign 
                            # this should match and be captured
                            # for PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE
          ~x';              # verbose modifier
$parts = preg_split($regex, $string, 0, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
print_r($parts);
?>
```

See [a demo on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/buGhU6) and on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/gF6cB1/1).

Answer (score 0):

@Jan is definitely using the ideal function `preg_split()`.  I'll offer an alternative pattern that doesn't need to use `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` or a capture group.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ZrZqP))

```
$txt = 'Lot99. Is it 1+3 or 5 or 6.53';
var_export(
    preg_split('~(?:\d+\.\d+|\w+|\S)\K *~', $txt, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'Lot99',
  1 => '.',
  2 => 'Is',
  3 => 'it',
  4 => '1',
  5 => '+',
  6 => '3',
  7 => 'or',
  8 => '5',
  9 => 'or',
  10 => '6.53',
)
```

Effectively, the pattern says match 1. a single float value 2. one or more consecutive number/letters/underscores or 3. a single non-whitespace character THEN forget the matched characters and then consume zero or more spaces.  The spaces are the only characters discarded while splitting.